# Deploy command doesn't use --allow-unauthenticated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've written a google function to impersonate a service account for generating signed urls. However after I deploy using the below command, the allow unauthenticated option isn't enabled.

```
gcloud functions deploy func-sa-test2 \
--entry-point main \
--runtime python39 \
--impersonate-service-account sa-email \
--service-account sa-email \
--trigger-http \
--allow-unauthenticated
```

I have to deploy it again using the below command to enable that option separately.

```
gcloud functions deploy func-sa-test2 --allow-unauthenticated
```

How can I somehow deploy it correctly with a single command. Thanks!

Comment: What's you error?

Comment: In addition to `--verbosity=debug`, it would also be useful to tack `--log-http` onto the commands to see whether there's a difference in the underlying calls

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere There's no error. It's just that the allow unauthenticated option isn't getting enabled when passed along with the deploy command, and I'm required to deploy again with just that option a second time

Comment: If you add the `--log-http` command line option, you should see the command (API call) that @guillaume-blaquiere mentions. Behind the scenes, setting the Function's IAM policy is a separate step. You might have identified a bug.

Comment: The CLI flag **--impersonate-service-account** does not set the identity that Cloud Functions uses to sign URLs. It sets the identity that the CLI command will use to deploy the function. I will bet that the impersonated service account does not have the role **Cloud Functions Admin** or better, so the set IAM policy fails. This also indicates a bug with the CLI not reporting failure to set the IAM policy.

Comment: @JohnHanley you're right, the service account only has the **Cloud Functions Developer** role, I can understand I might require admin access for setting **--allow-unauthenticated**, it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "no error" is strange. Be sure that the impersonated service account has the role `roles/cloudfunctions.admin`.

Indeed, with your first command, you deploy with GCLOUD and the credentials of th sa-email. The sa-email must have the permission to set IAM policies on the functions

In the second command, you no longer use the sa-email credential, but YOUR user credential, this time it's work because YOU have the permissions.

---

To investigate, you can try to run that command

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding  func-sa-test2 --member="allUsers" --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" --impersonate-service-account sa-email
```

If you haven't the permission, it should fail

Comment: You are correct, but the OP is confused about the impersonated service account. He is trying to use an impersonated identity to change who signs URLs which will not work because the **--service-account** sets the identity that the function will use. The **--impersonate-service-account** sets the identity that the CLI uses to deploy the function and has no impact on the identity that the function uses later on to sign URLs.

Comment: This totally makes sense! My service account only has the `cloudfunctions.developer` access.

Answer (score 2):

Service accounts doesn't contain "cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy" permission. That’s the reason you are unable to enable the flag **--allow-unauthenticated** in a single command.

If your service account has one of these roles (**Cloud Functions Admin**, Firebase Admin, Firebase Develop Admin, Firebase Extensions API Service Agent, Owner, Security Admin) then you can enable **--allow-unauthenticated** in a single command.

When executing it in a separate command you may have **owner permission**. So you didn't get any issues.

If you want you can use a console **to avoid such problems**.

Comment: You are correct for the **impersonated service account** and the fact that set IAM policy is failing without an error message indicates a CLI bug. Also, the user incorrectly thinks **--impersonate-service-account** will change the identity used to sign URLs by Cloud Functions.